# Get Multiple IP addresses from one variable using Perl to print a list

Tags: perl, ip, ip-address, country

I need the script to print out the list of IP addresses line by line with the corresponding username and email address and the country. How do I get the multiple IP addresses to execute a command? I tried doing a loop but it only showed me one line of IP addresses. I would like my output to look like:

```
1 | login | emailadd@yahoo.com | 160.79.208.82 | United States
16 | login1 | emailadd@yahoo.com | 61.95.83.10 | Italy
23 | login2 | emailadd@gmail.com | 81.48.63.93 | Australia
36 | login3 | emailadd@yahoo.com | 38.117.170.82 | Japan
51 | login4 | emailadd@gmail.com | 2.233.30.85 | Mexico
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use lib '~/lib';
use strict;
use Net::IPInfoDB;

my $g = Net::IPInfoDB->new;
$g->key(api_key);

my $login = '1 | login | emailadd@yahoo.com | 160.79.208.82
            16 | login1 | emailadd@yahoo.com | 61.95.83.10 
            23 | login2 | emailadd@gmail.com | 81.48.63.93 
            36 | login3 | emailadd@yahoo.com | 38.117.170.82 
            51 | login4 | emailadd@gmail.com | 2.233.30.85';

$login =~ /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/;

my $city = $g->get_city("$1");
my $addr = $g->get_country("$1");


printf "$login | (%s, %s)\n",
$city->city_name, $addr->country_name;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not using arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting only one IP address, because it is exactly what you are doing by applying the regex ONCE on the whole $login.

```
#we split $login into an array, line-by-line
my @lines = split("\n",$login);
for my $line (@lines) {
    #now we iterate through every line one-by-one
    $line =~ /(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/;

    print $+{"ip"}."\n";
}
```

Here we iterated through every line on $login and we applied the regex for each line individually..Instead of printing ofc you can do whatever you want with that ip.

Also I'm using here named match, which is only my preference, you don't have to use it.

Comment: Thanks! It shows all the IP addresses in a list. How do I get it to show the Country as well next to the IP address? I'd actually like the output to look like this with the line breaks ( I can't get it to show )

1 | login | emailadd@yahoo.com | 160.79.208.82 | United States <br>
16 | login1 | emailadd@yahoo.com | 61.95.83.10 | Italy  
23 | login2 | emailadd@gmail.com | 81.48.63.93 | Australia  
36 | login3 | emailadd@yahoo.com | 38.117.170.82 | Japan  
51 | login4 | emailadd@gmail.com | 2.233.30.85 | Mexico

Comment: well instead of 'print $+{"ip"}' put my $country=get_somehow_the_country(); $line .= " | $country"; print "$line\n"; As far as I see you only need to append the country to the existing line

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to not using the array, here's a solution to getting the IP addresses.

```
while ($login =~ m/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: @ikegami Is using `$&` a bad practice?

Comment: Thanks this worked but stopped with these errors: Use of uninitialized value in string ne at /Library/Perl/5.12/Net/IPInfoDB.pm line 101.
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in join or string at /Library/Perl/5.12/Net/IPInfoDB.pm line 57.
Can't call method "country_name" on an undefined value at array.pl line 48. Maybe it can't recognize the IP.

how do I also show 1 | login | emailadd@yahoo.com | 160.79.208.82 on each line? Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you copying your variables before exiting the loop? The scope of `$1` is only within the loop, so you either have to call `get_city` and `get_country` inside the loop, or copy the IP addresses and iterate through them after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `/g` to find all matches.

```
my @ips = /(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/g;
```

That said, you obviously want the 4th field, so let's actually do that rather than risking getting something from the third field.

```
sub trim { my ($s) = @_; $s =~ s/^\s+//; $s =~ s/\s+\z//; $s }

for (split /^/m, $login) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = map trim($_), split /\|/;
   my $ip = $fields[2];
   ...
}
```